# Regex to match a C-style multiline comment

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string for e.g.

```
String src = "How are things today /* this is comment *\*/ and is your code  /*\* this is another comment */ working?"
```

I want to remove `/* this is comment *\*/`  and `/** this is another comment */` substrings from the `src` string.

I tried to use regex but failed due to less experience.

Comment: Parsing Java code with regex is not something I'd recommend.

Comment: @Confluence, I am not sure what could be the best option to achieve the result? Can you suggest one.

Comment: What regex did you try? As you already say that you have tried something, you can as well just paste it here, so we can see your approach. We can go into more/less details about the solutions depending on your experience.

Comment: /\\*.*\\/ this is what I used ...And it removed whole string after the first match

Comment: from https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch07s06.html, you can use either `/\*.*?\*/` or `/\*[\s\S]*?\*/`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try using this regex (Single line comments only):

```
String src ="How are things today /* this is comment */ and is your code /* this is another comment */ working?";
String result=src.replaceAll("/\\*.*?\\*/","");//single line comments
System.out.println(result);
```

**REGEX explained:**

> Match the character "/" literally
>
> Match the character "*" literally
>
> "." Match any single character
>
> "*?" Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding
>   as needed (lazy)
>
> Match the character "*" literally
>
> Match the character "/" literally

Alternatively here is regex for single and multi-line comments by adding *(?s)*:

```
//note the added \n which wont work with previous regex
String src ="How are things today /* this\n is comment */ and is your code /* this is another comment */ working?";
String result=src.replaceAll("(?s)/\\*.*?\\*/","");
System.out.println(result);
```

**Reference:**

- https://www.regular-expressions.info/examplesprogrammer.html

Comment: It will be fun when you have a string that contains the comment sequences.

Comment: Can you explain how the multiline regex works? I don't understand the *(?s)* (and the link doesn't help in that regard).

Comment: @nhahtdh +1 Lol yes another story completely ( I guess you just check the String before for any conflicating series of characters and replace them with something safe until regex is complete then replace them back?

Comment: @brimborium: `(?s)` is DOTALL, which means `.` will match even new line character (which it won't match by default).

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: Something safe <-- quite tricky if you want it 100% safe. Before that, we have to recognize the bounds of the string first.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks, gskinner didn't know about that one. ;)

Comment: in PHP it wont works as "/\\*.*?\\*/", but "/(\/\*.*?\*\/)+/"

Answer (score 59):

The *best multiline comment regex* is an unrolled version of `(?s)/\*.*?\*/` that looks like

```
String pat = "/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/";
```

See the [regex demo and explanation at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dU5fO8/73).

In short,

- `/\*` - match the comment start `/*`
- `[^*]*\*+` - match 0+ characters other than `*` followed with 1+ literal `*`
- `(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `[^/*][^*]*\*+` - not a `/` or `*` (matched with `[^/*]`) followed with 0+ non-asterisk characters (`[^*]*`) followed with 1+ asterisks (`\*+`)
- `/` - closing `/`

[David's regex](https://regex101.com/r/dU5fO8/2) needs *26 steps* to find the match in my example string, and [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/KBZ5Y0/1) needs just *12 steps*. With huge inputs, David's regex is likely to fail with a stack overflow issue or something similar because the `.*?` lazy dot matching is inefficient due to lazy pattern expansion at each location the regex engine performs, while my pattern matches linear chunks of text in one go.

Comment: How did you come up with this?

Comment: @AT-Aoi It is basically taken from *Mastering Regular Expressions*, *Removing C Comments*  section.

Comment: This has a bug, it incorrectly extends comments that consists only of asterisks past the closing `*/`. A small, syntactically correct C snippet demonstrates this issue: `/**/ Incorrectly removed /**/`.

Comment: @jerry I introduced a change some time ago, trying to accommodate for repeating asterisks at the start. Rolled back to the original version. Now, your issue is [not repro](https://regex101.com/r/dU5fO8/73).

Comment: An assumption like "because the .*? lazy dot matching is inefficient" cannot be made in general without referring to a specific regex engine and version. Even if it holds true for some engine, it may not hold true for another one and not even for a different version of the same one. It's not defined how a regex engine works; that's comparable to SQL not specifying how a database really works under the hood.

Comment: Your ``my regex`` link still links to the old broken version that fails for /***/.

Comment: awesome solution :)

Comment: Do you know how to fix the case where the comment is actually a part of a string? I posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66301705

Comment: How about finding multiple line comments having a certain word like `foo`?

Comment: @HasanuzzamanSattar Using POSIX-like pattern here would be hard, [I'd suggest](https://regex101.com/r/dU5fO8/177) `(?s)/\*(?:(?!/\*|\*/).)*?foo(?:(?!/\*|\*/).)*\*/`, but note it is not going to be efficient. The best approach here is to match all of the comments and just filter out those containing some other pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's not working at Dreamweaver search tool. I want match all c/C++ style multiple lines comments where `foo` word is present inside the comment at least once.

Comment: @HasanuzzamanSattar Then it does not use Java / PCRE compliant regex engine. Probably, they use some kind of ECMAScript there, so you need `/\*(?:(?!/\*|\*/)[\w\W])*?foo(?:(?!/\*|\*/)[\w\W])*\*/`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
(//[^\n]*$|/(?!\\)\*[\s\S]*?\*(?!\\)/)
```

If you want to exclude the parts enclused in " "
then use:

```
(\"[^\"]*\"(?!\\))|(//[^\n]*$|/(?!\\)\*[\s\S]*?\*(?!\\)/)
```

the first capturing group identifies all " " parts and second capturing group gives you comments (both single line and multi line)

copy the regular expression to [regex101](http://regex101.com) if you want explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
(?s)(?i)(^|\s+?)(\/\*)((.)(?!\*\/))*?(this)(.*?)(\*\/)
```

You can find inner comment's words:

[image]

Comment: in this example finding word is "this"

Answer (score 0):

Can't parse C/C++ style comments in Java source directly.
Quoted strings have to be parsed at the same time and within the same regex
because the string may embed `/*` or `//`, the start of a comment when it is just part
of the string.

Note there is additional regex consideration needs if *raw strings* constructs
are possible in the language.

The regex that does this feat is this.
Where group 1 contains the ***Comment*** and group 2 contains the ***Non-Comment***.
For example if you were removing comments  it would be:

Find
`(/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\]|\\(?:\r?\n)?)*?(?:\r?\n|$))|("[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|[\S\s][^/"'\\]*)`

Replace
`$2`

---

Stringed:
`"(/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\\\]|\\\\(?:\\r?\\n)?)*?(?:\\r?\\n|$))|(\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\\S\\s][^\"\\\\]*)*\"|'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\\S\\s][^'\\\\]*)*'|[\\S\\s][^/\"'\\\\]*)"`

Answer (score -1):

```
System.out.println(src.replaceAll("\\/\\*.*?\\*\\/ ?", ""));
```

You have to use the non-greedy-quantifier ? to get the regex working.
I also added a ' ?' at the end of the regex to remove one space.

Answer (score -1):

Try this which worked for me:

```
System.out.println(src.replaceAll("(\/\*.*?\*\/)+",""));
```

Answer (score -1):

This could be the best approach for multi-line comments

`System.out.println(text.replaceAll("\\/\\*[\\s\\S]*?\\*\\/", ""));`