# Regular expression to find C style block comments

Tags: regex

How to find this pattern using regex?

C style block comments

`/* xxxxxxxxxxxx */`

Comment: What if `/*` is on the same line and after a `//`, meaning it does not start a comment?

Comment: No, I do not need to handle such situation

Comment: Besides using regular expressions, if you wanted to go all-out you could use a language parser with a C (or whatever) language grammar. Examples are yacc, javacc, antlr

Comment: See this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086617/removing-comments-with-a-sliding-window-without-nested-while-loops#comment22966260_16086617) to a question about recognizing C comments for some ideas about the complexity of dealing with C comments 'properly' (meaning 'in the way that a C compiler must deal with C comments').  It is not straight-forward.  You're probably dealing only with simple comments — but spare a thought for the compiler writer.  I suspect there are other relevant questions and answers too. (No; this question is not a duplicate of the one referenced.)

Comment: I tried write using java as "\\/\\*(\\*(?!\\/)|[^*])*\\*\\" but with match function of String class, it throw an exception of java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 23. Do some one know why ?

Comment: This worked for me: \/\*.*?\*\/

Answer (score 43):

Try using

```
\/\*(\*(?!\/)|[^*])*\*\/
```

to capture single line and multi-line block comments. It searches for `/*` followed by any number of either:

- an `*` that is not followed by a `/`
- any char *except* `*`

and then the closing `*/` again.

Comment: You don't need to match whitespace characters in a separate branch;  `[^*/]` has them covered.  All the `|\s` does is open you up to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).  Also, you need to get that slash out of there, or your regex will fail to match comments with slashes inside them.

Comment: Changed to your suggestions (although OP said, that comments with slashes seem not to be an issue)

Comment: why not `/\*(.(?!\*/))*\*/` ? first an `/*` then any character not followed by `*/` then `*/`

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use ```/\*.*?\*/```.

Comment: I like to add raw-string `r"/[*]([^*]|([*][^/]))*[*]/"` as it worked in python !

Comment: @ensonic It would definitely be simpler, however, `?`s are not always as performant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36328890/3492994

Comment: @shuva, I quite like your regex, but right now it misses `/* ... **/` since the second to last star would match `[*][^/]`, but this also eats the final star.  As a quick fix I used `r"/[*]([^*]|([*][^/]))*[*]+/"` (note the extra plus at the end, allowing additional trailing stars.)

Comment: friendly reminder that this one is wrong, it does not handle the * correctly.

Comment: @ensonic: Is it just me or does your solution not cover multiline comments?

Comment: @AndrewShi It is? Just tried it again at regexr.com and it worked just fine for single and multi line block comments.

Comment: @Campfire I think this depends on the specific regex parser, some include newline in *, some don't