# regex: extract text between two string with text that match a specific word

Tags: c, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm refactorying a very big C project and I need to find out some part of code written by specific programmer.
Fortunately every guy involved in this project mark his own code using his email address in standard C style comments.

Ok, someone could say that this could be achieved easily with a grep from command line, but this is not my goal: I may need to remove this comments or substitute them with other text so regex is the only solution.

Ex.

```
/*********************************************
 *
 * ... some text ....
 *
 * author: user@domain.com
 *
 *********************************************/
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160190/regular-expression-to-find-c-style-block-comments) I found the right expression to search for C style comments which is:

```
\/\*(\*(?!\/)|[^*])*\*\/
```

But that is not enough! I only need the comments which contains a specific email address. Fortunately the domain of email address I'm looking for seems to be unique in the whole project so this could make it simpler.

I think I must use some positive lookahead assertion, I've tried this one:

```
(\/\*)(\*(?!\/)|[^*](?=.*domain.com))*(\*\/)
```

but it doesn't run!
Any advice?

Comment: [`\/\*[^*]*(?:\*(?!\/)[^*]*)*@domain\.com[^*]*(?:\*(?!\/)[^*]*)*\*\/`](https://regex101.com/r/nW8uP2/1)?

Comment: `\/\*.*author: .*@domain\.com.*?\*\/` should match.

Comment: @Saleem, [it will overfire](https://regex101.com/r/mV2bU2/1), do not rely on `.*` when you deal with matching inside a marked up text.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are correct. One can easily make a mistake and it will overfire. but If you can see, I'm using `.*?` (non-greedy) at end. just before `*/` here is my test case. https://regex101.com/r/mV2bU2/2

Comment: as @WiktorStribiżew pointed out, my regex can potentially overfire so here is another version with fix `\/\*.*author: .*@domain\.com.*?\*\/\s` see https://regex101.com/r/mV2bU2/3

Comment: Why do you dismiss grep as a tool of choice? It's regex based after all and  it would give you a survey of where the author's email occurs (eg. in string literals ). To actually substitute content, you might use the cli tool sed, who matches lines by regex too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Thank you! your solution runs very well!

Comment: @collapsar :  I could use grep + sed  but I guess it is simpler using  regex multiline search/replace feature provided by some code editors

Comment: Stackoverflow is _not_ a forum. Read the [faq] and note that we do not put [solved] and other stuff in the title. There is a checkmark next to each answer that you're supposed to use to indicate which answer solved your problem.

Comment: You're right, sorry for the mistake. However, how can I mark an answer when users reply with comments instead of using regular answer? Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\/\*[^*]*(?:\*(?!\/)[^*]*)*@domain\.com[^*]*(?:\*(?!\/)[^*]*)*\*\/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nW8uP2/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `/\*` - comment start
- `[^*]*(?:\*(?!\/)[^*]*)*` - everything but `*/`
- `@domain\.com` - literal `domain.com`
- `[^*]*(?:\*(?!\/)[^*]*)*` - everything but `*/`
- `\*\/` - comment end

A faster alternative (as the first part will be looking for everything but the comment end *and* the word `@domain`):

```
\/\*[^*@]*(?:\*(?!\/)[^*@]*|@(?!domain\.com)[^*@]*)*@domain\.com[^*]*(?:\*(?!\/)[^*]*)*\*\/
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/nW8uP2/2)

In these patterns, I used an unrolled construct for `(\*(?!\/)|[^*])*`: `[^*]*(?:\*(?!\/)[^*]*)*`. [Unrolling](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) helps construct more efficient patterns.