# Linux CLI grep pattern matching multiline comment

Tags: regex, linux, grep, comments, multiline

How to write linux's grep regex to match multi line comment like this

```
/*
comment 
body
*/
```

so grep matches 4 lines in the case as above.
Note any of the single lines of the comment can start with white chars (for example tab or spaces)

I do not mind if the regex pattern also matches single line comment

```
/* comment body */
```

but this is not required since I already have a pattern addressing that need.

If matching multi line commend by using grep is not doable then I can use sed, awk, etc. But grep with its regex is preferred.

Comment: You can't. `grep` only operates on one line at a time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to match a C-style multiline comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13014947/608639), [Regular expression to find C style block comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16160190/608639), etc.

Comment: @Barmar how about sed/awk? do they also work one line at the time? Using multi line switch in regex with grep will not make any difference?

Comment: `awk` allows you to set variables and refer back to them. So when you match the start of a comment you can set a variable, and then other statements can check that variable and behave accordingly for the lines after it. When you match the end, you unset the variable.