# Comments /* ... */: What is the correct regex expression?

Tags: python, regex

I have a language where block comments look like this /* ... */ (could be multi-line). However, nested comments like /* /* ... */ */ are illegal. What would be the correct regex expression to match this?

I have:

> /\*(.*)?\*\/

But this would also match the second case which I don't want.

Comment: This will be matched `/* /* ... */` and the trailing `*/` will throw an error. The matching is rudimentary, not really intelligent, the first open, then the first close. Like `/\*(.*?)\*/` with the dot-all flag.

Comment: How about `^\/\*[^\/*]+\*\/$` ? (https://regex101.com/r/zy0UgL/1)

Comment: Thank you. I am using python and more specifically Tatsu as the parser generator.

Comment: @jrook in your example, if there is a star character inside a comment, it doesn't work. For instance in your example regex101 url, if you replace "did" with "di*d", it doesn't match anymore. Doing this using regexp the way it's asked would be extremely complicated if not impossible

Comment: or this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160190/regular-expression-to-find-c-style-block-comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular expression (in the true sense of the word) which matches non-nesting C-style comments is:

```
[/][*]([^*]|[*]*[^*/])*[*]*[*][/]
```

The `/` and `*` characters are literally matched, so they are here boxed in `[]` character class syntax as an alternative to backslash escaping. (The `/` is often used as a delimiter for regular expressions.)

The explanation follows.

Match the leading `/*` sequence:

```
[/][*]
```

Then match any mixture, including an empty mixture, of:

- individual characters that are not `*`; or
- sequences of zero or more `*` terminated by a character that is neither `*` nor `/`

:

```
      ([^*]|[*]*[^*/])*
```

Then match zero or more `*` characters:

```
                       [*]*
```

Finally, match the trailing sequence:

```
                            [*][/]
```

Comment: Great answer (upvoted). I'm curious why simulators like regex101 throw "pattern error" for [/], do you have a clue?

Comment: This regex will match `/* /* ... */ */` partially

Comment: @anubhava That is correct. The comment is this part `/* /* ... */`, which is followed followed by non-comment material `...*/` .   OP said that nested comments are "illegal"; without explaining what that means: are we supposed to not match this at all, or does it mean that nested comments are treated as they are in C or Cascading Style Sheets.

Comment: Well in that case `/\*.*?\*/` will also work

Comment: @anubhava That's a Perl "regular" expression, though, not a regular expression.

Comment: No I didn't mean `/` as regex delimiter. I meant `r'/\*.*?\*/'` as regex