# Matching multiline commands using regex(non greedy)

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract the following data

```
/** Hi **/
#define 1
/** Hi **/
#define something() \
here \
another one
/** HI 
 * SOmething
**/
```

I need to extract all the multi-line comments . I have tried this https://regex101.com/r/jD5bR1/1 but it doesnt seem to work

```
(^\/\*\*(.*?)\*\*\/)
```

What am I doing wrong? It is matching only the first comment. How do I match all multi line comments?

Comment: See [update](https://regex101.com/r/jD5bR1/2)

Comment: That works. Thanks :-).

Comment: Use a much better one from http://stackoverflow.com/a/36328890/3832970, you will only need to remove the initial and trailing `/*` and `*/` to get the final result.

Comment: [`/\*(.*?)\*/`](https://regex101.com/r/jD5bR1/3)