# How to match text between comment block in java regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have to match text between `/*` and `*/`. These are java block comments.

For now I created program that doesn't work as intended because it doesn't stop at closing token `*/`. Here is code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String s = "public void /* sdksd\n*k/sss\\d\nsd */ main class\n/*String s = null;*/trtgg";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?s)/\\*(.*)(?=\\*/)").matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String group = matcher.group(1);
            System.out.println("group="+group);
        }
}
```

It prints:

```
group= sdksd
*k/sss\d
sd */ main class
/*String s = null;
```

Expected output is :

```
group= sdksd
*k/sss\d
sd 
group=String s = null;
```

Why it doesn't stop at first closing token `*/`?

Is there other way to achieve this?

Comment: `.*` is greedy so you need to use `.*?` to make it lazy. Comment extraction can be pretty tricky though.

Comment: Use [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36328890/3832970). More than 4 times as few steps required to complete a match than the best one suggested by Jiri.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you don't allow nested comments, like `/* outer comment /* nested comment */ outer comment */`.

In Java, you can use non-greedy matching:

```
/\\*.*?\\*/
```

Or to avoid non-greedy matching (some regexes don't have it):

```
/\\*([^*]|\\*[^/])*\\*/
```

If you allow nested comments, the resulting language is non-regular and cannot be described by a true regular expression (it still might be possible even with Java's regular expression since it isn't strictly regular).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed to make regex engine match `(?=\\*/)` after single character is consumed by `.*` you need to make * as lazy .
Here is correct code:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?s)/\\*(.*?)(?=\\*/)").matcher(s);
```