# How to remove single and multi line comments from string in apex

Tags: regex, salesforce, apex

I have found this link to remove multiline comments :

[Regex to match a C-style multiline comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014947/regex-to-match-a-c-style-multiline-comment)

But this is not working for single line comments.Is there any efficient ways to remove single and multi comments using regex expression ?