# RegEx match end character only when other character is not present

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having quite some trouble to define a regEx that I'm needing....

Basically the idea is to detect all lines that end with a `,` or a `;` character. For this I have defined the following regex:

```
(,|;)$
```

Which works fine for this, but then I have the exception that if there's a `*` character within that line (not necessarily starting with, but at some position), then I don't want to detect that match. Based on this sample:

```
/**
 * Here there's a comment I don't want to find,
 * but after this comment I do
 */
detectMe;
other,
```

I would intend to find 2 groups, the first one

```
/**
 * Here there's a comment I don't want to find,
 * but after this comment I do
 */
detectMe;
```

And the second one

```
other,
```

I've tried many things such as non capturing groups, negative looks ahead and also start of a string with `[^\s*\*]` with no success. Is there a way to do this?

Some of the regEx I've tried...

```
^[^\*](.*?)(,|;)$
^[^\s*\*](.*?)(,|;)$
```

Comment: remove the `(.*?)` that is too broad and use `^([^*\r\n]*)[,;]$` to exclude `*` from the whole line.

Comment: Also note that Javascript has two string methods: `String.prototype.endsWith()` and `String.prototype.includes()`.

Comment: You may find it useful to read up on parsers and lexical analysis if you're going to be interpreting bodies of text (namely code). Here's a great introduction: https://medium.com/dailyjs/gentle-introduction-into-compilers-part-1-lexical-analysis-and-scanner-733246be6738

Comment: Do you want to match an optional C comment and the following line ending with `;` or `,`? See https://regex101.com/r/rWmSGj/1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is exactly what I needed! could you post it as an answer so I can mark it and give up vote? Works like a charm! - Now I'm trying to break it up and understand it

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52654533/3832970) below. You will find the explanation there and helpful links.

Comment: Another idea: [`/^[ \t]*(?!\/?\*)\S.*[;,]$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/eJYiZY/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match an optional C comment and the following line ending with `;` or `,` you may use

```
/(?:\/\*+[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/\r?\n)?.*[;,]$/gm
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rWmSGj/2)

**Details**

- `(?:\/\*+[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/\r?\n)?` - an optional (as there is a `?` quantifier after the group) [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `\/\*+[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/` - a [C comment pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36328890/3832970)
  - `\r?\n` - a CRLF or LF ending
- `.*[;,]$` - a whole line that ends with `;` or `,` (`$` is the end of a line anchor here due to `m` modifier).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[^*]*?[,;]$/gm
```

It will start by mathing any number of characters not being '`*`', then match '`,`' or '`;`' at the end of the line. It uses the `global` and `multiline` flags to match all lines.

Comment: This is almost what I needed! indeed, its matching the proper lines, the problem is that now the comment is not included over the first match, its discarded instead. Like this I get 'detectMe;' instead of '/**
 * Here there's a comment I don't want to find,
 * but after this comment I do
 */
detectMe;'

Comment: Well, you say, you don't want to find them. Doesn't that mean, that they should not match?