# Searching only for specific words in string excluding anything in between

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am looking for a pattern which can extract only the search words given in pattern and exclude any other words in between.

So for the input string...

```
2637:1888 log :[INFO] :    create    /* some comment*/    table mytab (n numeric)
```

... I need to extract 'create' and 'table'.

If anything else is in between create and table word I should be getting null.
I tried with various combination but I am not able to get much clue

If there is no comment in between create and table word then my pattern works 
i.e

```
(create)\s*(table)
```

What should I do?

Comment: First, remove the comments with `regexp_replace(col, '/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/', ' ')`, then run your regex.

Comment: @konardrudolph : Thanks for your reply to my query. I tried regexp_replace to my initial thought where I need to replace multiple spaces with single space between "create" and "table", which worked well. But later my requirement changed where I need to exclude any comment in between "create" and "table" word, for which you provided the pattern. I am not sure if there is a way where we can exclude regexp_replace function and get the required output with single pattern for the same output. May be I am getting crazy....

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
where col ~ '\ycreate(?:\s*/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/)*\s*table\y'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5rwewn/1) (`\y` replaced with PCRE `\b` for the demo purposes).

The pattern matches:

- `\y` - a word boundary
- `create` - a string `create`
- `(?:\s*/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/` - a [multiline C comment pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36328890/3832970)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `table` - a string `table`
- `\y` - a word boundary

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/SGZJ63576):

```
CREATE TABLE tabl1
    (test character varying)
;

INSERT INTO tabl1
    (test)
VALUES
    ('1: 2637:1888 log :[INFO] :    create  table mytab (n numeric)'),
    ('2: 2637:1888 log :[INFO] :    create    /* some comment*/  table mytab (n numeric)'),
    ('3: 2637:1888 log :[INFO] :    create    /* some comment*/   /**//* some comment2*/    table mytab (n numeric)'),
    ('4: 2637:1888 log :[INFO] :    create    WOW  table mytab (n numeric)')
;

select * from tabl1 where test ~ '\ycreate(?:\s*/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/)*\s*table\y';
```

Output:

[image]