# Regular expression to replace a substring within a String in python

Tags: python, regex

I have to replace a substring with another string in a file.

Below is the line which is present in the file.

Input:   `#pragma MESSAGE "Hello World" 0000=1 /* Clarification 0001: [[Specific Clarification]] */`

Expected Output: `#pragma MESSAGE "Hello World" 0000=1 # [[Specific Clarification]]`

Below is my code:

```
import re
line = r'#pragma MESSAGE "Hello World" 0000=1 /* Clarification 0001: [[Specific Clarification]] */'
comment = re.search(r'([\/\*]+).*([^\*\/]+)', line)
replace = re.search(r'([\[[]).*([\]]])', comment.group())
replaceWith = replace.group()
content_new = re.sub(r'([\/\*]).*([\*\/])', '# ' + replaceWith, line)
```

Is there an optimal solution for the above code?

Comment: What is `content`? What is the problem with the regex? If you need to replace, why do you use `re.search`, and even twice?

Comment: ive edited `content` with `line `. Is there any alternative way to approach this problem with one regex statement?

Comment: I am unable to do the search for replaceWith in a single regex statement.

Comment: `content_new = re.sub(r'/\*(.*?)\*/', lambda x: re.sub(r'.*(\[\[.*?]]).*', r'# \1', x.group(1)), line)`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/CzJdbt).

Comment: Two more ways: https://regex101.com/r/RbPmfB/1/ and https://regex101.com/r/RbPmfB/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match comments, say, with [Regex to match a C-style multiline comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36328890/3832970), and then replace the `[[...]]` substring inside the matches. This approach is safest, it won't fail if there is `[[` and no `]]` inside the comment, and there are several such comments in the string.

The sample code snippet [will look like](https://ideone.com/RqVenm)

```
import re
line = r'#pragma MESSAGE "Hello World" 0000=1 /* Clarification 0001: [[Specific Clarification]] */'
content_new = re.sub(r'/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/', lambda x: re.sub(r'.*(\[\[.*?]]).*', r'# \1', x.group()), line)
print(content_new)
```

Output: `#pragma MESSAGE "Hello World" 0000=1 # [[Specific Clarification]]`.

Details:

- `re.sub(r'/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/', ..., line)` - finds all C style comments in the string, and
- `lambda x: re.sub(r'.*(\[\[.*?]]).*', r'# \1', x.group())` is the replacement: `x` is the match data object with the comment text, it matches any text up to `[[`, then captures `[[` and then any text up to and including `]]`, and then matches the rest of the comment, and replaces with `#`, space and the Group 1 value. See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/oISnxL/1).